# osx - My application doesn't appear in the Dock when running. How can I fix this?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, dock

I just picked up the code for an application our overseas developer has made for us. For some reason, when the application starts, no icon pops up in the Dock (with the little blue circle below).

If I manually add the app to the Dock and start it from the Dock, it will run the application, but the icon won't be illuminated with the blue circle (no indication that it is running).

Where would I have to start in order to solve this problem? (e.g. to make it clear that the application is running by having an icon in the Dock with the blue circle below it).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either you are running Mac OS X Lion with the indicator turned off (see Dock settings) or you app is configured as a UI element in the Info.plist file (`LSUIElement` is `YES`).

Set `LSUIElement` to `NO`/`false` in Info.plist.